# unpack multiple lists when calling a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a function `pack()` that takes any number of arguments.
I also have two lists, `L1=[1,2]` and `L2=[3,4]`

I can call `pack(5, 6, *L1)` or I can call `pack(5, 6, *L2)`, but calling `pack(5, 6, *L1, *L2)` fails.  How can I get the equivalent of `pack(5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> pack(5, 6, *chain(L1, L2))
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer - beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple solution

```
>>> def pack(*args):
    print 'in pack'

>>> L1 = [1,2]
>>> L2 = [3,4]
>>> pack(5,6,*L1)
in pack
>>> pack(5,6,*L1,*L2)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pack(5,6,*(L1 + L2))
in pack
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that's an old thread, but starting with python 3 you can perfectly do [multiple unpacking](https://github.com/arogozhnikov/python3_with_pleasure#multiple-unpacking) without chaining:

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2]
>>> L2 = [3, 4]
>>> print(5, 6, *L1, *L2)
5 6 1 2 3 4
```